# Proving the element of a symmetry group $\sigma^i \in S_n$ is of order $n$ and length $n$ only when $(n,i) = 1$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Start with element of $S_n$ as $\sigma^i$ which permutes an element of the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$, call it, $a_k \to a_{k+i}$ So $({\sigma^i})^2$ would permute $a_k \to a_{k+2i}$ If $k+i > n$, the element is shifted the remainder from the starting point. It can be written as $k + i (\mod{n})$.

$\sigma ^i$ acts as an element of the additive group ($\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$,$+$)

I'm trying to prove that $\sigma^i$ is an $n-$cycle if $(i,n) = 1$ so now I can show $(\sigma ^i)^t \equiv e (\mod{n})$ $t = n$ if $(\sigma^i)$ is relatively prime to $n$. Is this the right route? Then I relate it back to $S_n$ so $(\sigma^i)^n = e$ meaning $|\sigma^i| = n$ does this mean it's an $n-$cycle?

Comment: Ah i just found out that just because the permutation's order is $n$, it doesn't have to be an $n-$cycle so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Show that the elements $(\sigma^i)^k(1)$ are distinct for $k=1,\ldots,n$; it follows that the permutations $(\sigma^i)^k$ must be distinct for $k=1,\ldots,n$ and hence that $\sigma^i$ is an $n$-cycle.

To do this, suppose that $(\sigma^i)^k(1)=(\sigma^i)^\ell(1)$ for some $k,\ell$ such that $1\le k<\ell\le n$, and let $d=\ell-k$.

- Show that $n\mid di$, and then use the hypothesis that $\gcd(n,i)=1$.

Comment: When showing the above is distinct, am I restricting $ik < n$? otherwise $\sigma^{ik}(1) = 1 + ik$ and it's out of bounds. Assuming I can show that it is distinct, when you say $\sigma^i$ is an $n-$cycle, do you mean that its cycle decomp in total is of length $n$ or it is a single cycle of $n$?I think it's the former, right?

Comment: Ah man this is so much simpler! first assume it's an $n-$cycle by showing there are no fixed integers (aka all elements are permuted) then show that $(i,n) = 1$. Thanks I'll accept this.

Comment: @Obliv: You’re welcome. (To answer the initial questions, no, I wasn’t restricting $ik$: $(\sigma^i)^k$ is meaningful for all $k$. Of course $1+ik$ has to be reduced to the congruent value in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. And an $n$-cycle is by definition a single cycle of length $n$.) In your second comment you’re proving the opposite implication. I was suggesting a way to prove that if $(i,n)=1$, then $\sigma^i$ is an $n$-cycle; in the comment you’re proving that if it’s an $n$-cycle, then $(i,n)=1$ (which is indeed the easier direction).